# Gitlab-CI how to reference source from another project?

Tags: ant, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two projects, first is SOURCES (technical base) and second is an ant software.
I have create a gitlab-ci.yml on the second project but the build pipeline is always in error because sources libraries are not referenced.

In my build.xml, sources are referenced like this: *${SOURCES_DIRRECTORY}/folder/lib/library.jar*
In the gitlab-ci.yml I can set *SOURCES_DIRRECTORY* but putting the url of the other project doesn't seem to work.

A prohibited solution is to add the sources in an local lib folder. (so as not to duplicate)

Is it possible to reference another gitlab project from my CI ?
Otherwise, how can I retrieve and use the artifact generated by the sources project to obtain the libraries on my software project?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Possible solution could be download the artifacts from the job inside the other project using the APIs
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-the-artifacts-archive

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried to do a curl on the desired resource. The problem is that although my token is good it still downloads the gitlab login page in html format

Do you know why I can't curl my resource?

Comment: How is the curl that you use? I write an answer for better editing of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GitLab CI APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-the-artifacts-archive) to download the artifacts made in the other project.

I do something similar in one of my project and it work for me

```
curl -k --location --output artifacts.zip --header  "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/devel/download?job=$STAGE_NAME"
```

In this case i download the artifacts made by another branch in the same project, so I already have setted by default the variables and I can use `JOB-TOKEN`, instead you should use the `PRIVATE-TOKEN` that is an ACCESS TOKEN with the API permission grant. You should have something like that

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=test"
```

Comment: On your advice and documentation [Gitlab CI downloading artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-artifacts),
I attempted to download the artifact and specifically the desired source:
`curl -k --location --output [output]/artifact.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/api/v4/projects/[project ID]/jobs/[Job ID]/artifacts/devel/download?job=package"`
and
`cat [output]/artifact.zip`

The uploaded content is always the gitlab login page (in html)...
URL problem? Rights issue? Permission problem?

Comment: I think is an URL problem `/api/v4` url path is already inside the `$CI_API_V4_URL` variable, can you try without it?

Comment: Excuse me, bad copy/paste. For my tests the URL is directly written. I don't use the variable. `"[URL]/projects/[project ID]/jobs/[Job ID]/artifacts/devel/download?job=package"`

Comment: Ok, probably can be also a permission problem, I never tried this, so I don't know if a job have permission on another project like in your case. You can try to generate an access token in the second project ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html ) and pass it in the curl `--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>"` instead of use `JOB-TOKEN`

Comment: I tested :
`curl -k --location --output artifact.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [target project token]" "[url v4]/projects/[project id]/pipelines/[pipeline id]"`
and your example `curl -k --location --output artifact.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: [target project token]" "[url v4]/projects/[project id]/jobs/artifacts/main/ download?job=package"`

I specify that the artifact of the targeted job package is correct

Comment: it work ! thanks a lot !
`"$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/"`